# CSS - How to make inverted border-bottom with curved edges?

Tags: html, css

I've been looking everywhere and couldn't find this exact example:
[image: Curved CSS border bottom]

I managed to do this, but as you can see, it's not inverted and not curved:

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;

}
.inner i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.inner .top {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.inner .bottom {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -22px;
}
.inner .left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.inner .right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
.content {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <i class="bottom right"></i>
    <i class="bottom left"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible? I want it to as short as possible (height), like the image - and also I don't want to use an image or SVG (I tried that and it looks weird) I want to use this with dynamic width.

Comment: Can you use SVG? That is probably the way to go for this one, though I bet you could do it with just CSS and HTML but it might be kind of clunky

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried but when I change the width it looks weird (becomes shorter)

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/oNEWzOV

Comment: You can increase 0.25em to somewhere between 0.25 to 0.5 for the perfect curve that you need.

Comment: @m4n0 that was fast! it looks exactly the same. thank you!!! feel free to post this as an answer and I will mark this as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of [`border-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top) instead of `border-bottom`

```css
.border-curve {
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(180deg 100% 52%);
  border-radius: 0.35em;
}

body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-curve"></div>
```

Comment: Thnak you very much! it works perfectly